# MS Graph API - List channels API doesn't return full list of channels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to list all the channels with a specific team. However, there are some missing channels in the API response. There are 30 "active" private channels (as the creation limit) in my team, and it shows correctly in Microsoft Teams application. But when I list channels with API, it only response 24 private channels and there is no `@odata.nextLink` in the response. The same scenario happens when I list standard channels in that team.

Here is the format I send the request:
`GET /teams/{team-id}/channels?$filter=membershipType eq 'private'`

I tried to use /allChannels API as well, but it still acts like /channels API.

Below is the additional information: 
tenant-id: dcb0e1d1-6cde-4420-a658-ede52a8bead1 
team-id: bccdf0a4-ae60-45bc-8d4c-bd63a3106000 
request-id: 7bdadf71-729a-49dc-b677-769fbec2d91a 
client-request-id: 7bdadf71-729a-49dc-b677-769fbec2d91a 
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2023 02:15:26 GMT

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please try to check those 3 missing channel with API - GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id} , and make sure they were added membership type private - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @user20932669 - Could you please let us know if you need any further assistance here?

Comment: Hi @vicky-kumar, I got the channel-ids of the missing channels from Microsoft Teams admin center and checked their membership type, the membership type was indeed private. Surprisingly, when I tried the API with same setting today, I got full list of channels. Thank you for your help anyway.